# Trying to fill ui-grid from http.get JSON response based on a dropdown list, grid is blank dot.net

Tags: .net, angularjs, json

I'm back again.  Trying now to use ui-grid for the first time.  I was able to display data in he grid if I filled an array and set the array to bind to the grid, but if I am trying to set the results from and Http call that returns JSON the grid comes back blank no matter what I seem to try.

The same JSON response has no problem when filling a SELECT list on the same page, but when trying to fill the grid it does not seem to work.  I must be missing something.

UI-Grid version is: 3.0.1
Angular version is: 1.6.1

```html
//AttributeController.cs
 
using MVC_APP1.Models;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
 
 
namespace MVC_APP1.Controllers
{
    public class AttributeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Attribute/
 
        public ActionResult AttributeIndex()
        {
            Cafe_CPDEntities objEntity = new Cafe_CPDEntities();
            var data = objEntity.Attributes.ToList();
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
 
        public ActionResult getattributevalues(int id)
        {
            Cafe_CPDEntities objEntity = new Cafe_CPDEntities();
            var data = objEntity.Attribute_Value.Where(m=>m.Attribute_Key==id);
            //string test = data.FirstOrDefault().Attribute_Value_Desc;
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
 
    }
}
```

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  data-ng-app="attributeapp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/attribute.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/ui-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
 
<body>
    <div data-ng-controller="attributecontroller">
        <div data-ng-controller="gridController">
         <div data-ng-controller="attributevaluecontroller">
             <!--<select data-ng-model="detail.AttributeKey" data-ng-change="getattributevalues(detail.AttributeKey);" data-ng-options="Attribute.Attribute_Key as Attribute.Attribute_Desc for Attribute in Attributes"><option value="">--Select--</option></select>{{detail.AttributeKey}}<br />-->
             <select data-ng-model="detail.AttributeKey" data-ng-change="fillgrid(detail.AttributeKey);" data-ng-options="Attribute.Attribute_Key as Attribute.Attribute_Desc for Attribute in Attributes"><option value="">--Select--</option></select>{{detail.AttributeKey}}<br />
             <select data-ng-model="detail.AttributeValueKey" data-ng-options="Attribute_Value.Attribute_Value_Key as Attribute_Value.Attribute_Value_Desc for Attribute_Value in AttributeValues"><option value="">--Select--</option></select>{{detail.AttributeValueKey}}
 
            <br />
            <span data-ng-controller="saveattributecontroller">
                <input type="button" value="submit" data-ng-click="attributesave(detail)"/>
            </span>
 
 
        <br />
            <div class="gridStyle" data-ui-grid="gridAttributeValues">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 
</body>
</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```js
//Attribute.js
 
var myapp = angular.module('attributeapp', ['ui.grid']);
 
    myapp.controller('attributecontroller', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/Attribute/AttributeIndex/').then(function (response) {
            $scope.Attributes = response.data;
        })
    })
 
 
    myapp.controller('attributevaluecontroller', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.getattributevalues = function (id)
        {
            $http.get('/Attribute/getattributevalues/' + id).then(function (response) {
                $scope.A = id;
                                              $scope.AttributeValues =  response.data;
 
            })
        }
    })
 
 
    myapp.controller('saveattributecontroller', function($scope, $http){
        $scope.attributesave = function (Data) {
            var GetAll = new Object();
            GetAll.AttributeKey = Data.AttributeKey;
            GetAll.AttributeValueKey = Data.AttributeValueKey;
 
            $http.post("api/WebAPIAttribute/attributesave/", GetAll)
            .then(function (response) {
               
            }
            )
        }
    })
 
 
 
    myapp.controller('gridController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.fillgrid = function (id) {
            $http.get('/Attribute/getattributevalues/' + id).then(function (response) {
                $scope.A = id;
                $scope.AttributeValues = response.data;  // THIS FILLS THE SECOND DROPDOWN SUCCESSFULLY
 
                $scope.myDefs = [{ field: 'Attribute_Value_Key', displayName: 'Key'},
                 { field: 'Attribute_Value_Desc', displayName: 'Value' }];
                $scope.gridAttributeValues = { data: 'AttributeValues', columnDefs : 'myDefs' }  //THE GRID REMAINS BLANK?????
 
            })
        }
    })
```

Comment: Just updated the Plunker to your specific version of AngularJS and UI-Grid.  Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Did this help, matey?

Answer (score 0):

I put a little Plunker together for you, https://plnkr.co/edit/m870xaH3K95D4JqKhRtW?p=preview

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="gridStyle" data-ui-grid="gridAttributeValues"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript/AngularJS:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.gridAttributeValues = {
    columnDefs: [{
      field: 'Attribute_Value_Key',
      displayName: 'Key',
      enableColumnMenu: false 
    }, {
      field: 'Attribute_Value_Desc',
      displayName: 'Value',
      enableColumnMenu: false 
    }]
  }

  $http.get('data.json')
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.AttributeValues = response.data; // THIS FILLS THE SECOND DROPDOWN SUCCESSFULLY
      $scope.gridAttributeValues.data = response.data; //THE GRID NOW HAS DATA!!!!!!
    });
}]);
```

The trick is to define the columns "outside" the $http response.